# Can I use "Me too" like subject?

Tags: usage, pronouns, colloquial-language

Can I use "Me too" like subject in an answer?

If someone says,

> I am Italian.

I could say "Me too!" in response, but could I say

> Me too am Italian?

If not, why not?

It is confusing because "I too!" isn't an idiomatic response, even though "I too am Italian." is grammatical and could be a response.

Comment: Would you say Me am Italian? Can you explain why you would want to say "Me too am Italian" instead of I am Italian?

Comment: Just curiosity.

Comment: @Colleen I'm inclined to leave this question open since the gist of what it's asking is "can "me too" be the subject of a sentence?"

Comment: +1 DEAD but some expansion on "Just curiosity" would be helpful. What made you choose the phrase "Me too," @Mattew ?

Comment: @DEAD I was also hoping for something more than idle curiosity as well because 'me too' usage does break grammar rules in some situations. My concern is fielding a bunch of "Is this correct?" questions when there's no explanation of why the asker wants to put those words together. Some of those question might just happen to be interesting by coincidence, but any question that can be answered with a yes or no as it is written needs some  improvement in my opinion. Maybe we could add some of what stangdon has intuited is confusing about it and reopen.

Comment: Fair enough @Colleen.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I had this doubt from before knowing the site.

Comment: @Mattew _Doubt_ is not synonymous with _question._

Comment: @P.E.Dant Ah, I'd understand another thing. I just translated "Son solo curioso" in English. I didn't understand what synonyms you need to.

Comment: Googe translate is not a useful substitute for a real teacher or book to learners of any language.

Comment: I don't use Google Translate.

Comment: Mattew - I've added some explanation that might help get the question re-opened. If you disagree with what I've written there, you can roll-back to your original revision by clicking on the "Edited..." link over my icon.

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot.  When "I" is the subject of the sentence, it has to be the subject pronoun, *I*, not the object pronoun, *me*.  "Me am" is always wrong.

You might ask:
*"But don't people say 'Me too!' in response to a statement like, 'I am Italian'?  Shouldn't it be 'I too'?"*

Yes, maybe people should say "I too" to be strictly correct, but in practice nobody says that, and it sounds very stiff and formal.  "Me too" is idiomatic.  The only time you would say "I too" is if you're rephrasing the entire sentence: "I too am Italian!"

References: 
[Who caught the fish?](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2009/11/who-caught-the-fish.html)
[Me too?  I too?](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2010/08/me-too-i-too.html)